# Continue with Jenkins Pipeline after checking the status of stand-alone Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am running a Jenkins Pipeline. After some steps in the same pipeline, I want to check the `Last Build` status of another stand-alone job.

If the status is successful, then continue with the `Pipeline`, otherwise exit the `Pipeline`.

I want to do this in the Groovy Job DSL file and inside shell.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You can try doing a multi-job pipeline, and only continue on success of a previous job.  As Tupteq mentioned, you should put some examples of what you have tried in your question to make it easier to answer.